# BIDS keeps crashing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I am working on `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` and `BIDS Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.446` , The problem is it keeps crashing, It just restarts itself.

Did some googling and found this Hotfix [`Visual Studio 2008 SP1 crashes when you open a BIDS project`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2399730). I have download and applied the hotfix but the issue persists.

It seems like it is a well known issue as Microsoft decided to issue a hotfix for it. But the hotfix didnt solve the issue for me.

Has someone else also experienced it and how did you fix it? any suggestions or pointer in the right direction is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I did re-installed BIDS from scratch.

Comment: just re-installing solved the issue or did you download and hotfix as well ?

Comment: Yes, it indeed fixed that recursive crashing issue. After you reinstall, install the hotfix as well before you start working on any project.

Comment: grrrrr I love BIDS for all the powerful tools it provide for reporting but these silly tantrums just ruins it all. few weeks ago it was throwing some silly error like "Attempted to read or write protected memory bla bla" and believe me or not a windows layout reset fixed the issue lol. Anyway cheers buddy will give it a go. Ta

Comment: No issues, Welcome. Do let me know if it fixes the problem you are facing.